# rails6.0 + omniauth-google-oauth2 で認証を行うとuninitialized constantがおきる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のページを参考に実装を行いました。

[gem omniauth-google-oauth2 で認証させる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/bino98/items/596b5cffeca7c104bd90)

その後いくつかのバージョン違いによるエラーは取り除けたのですが、googleの認証画面からリダイレクトしたときに以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
uninitialized constant Users::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

この問題の対処方法がわかる方教えてください。

---

Gemfile

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

```ruby
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
   def google
     @user = User.find_for_google(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

     if @user.persisted?
       flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'
       sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
     else
       session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
       redirect_to new_user_registration_url
     end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,:trackable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i(google)

  # protected
  def self.find_for_google(auth)
    user = User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)

    unless user
      user = User.create(name:     auth.info.name,
                         provider: auth.provider,
                         uid:      auth.uid,
                         token:    auth.credentials.token,
                         password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
                         meta:     auth.to_yaml)
    end
    user
  end
end
```

devise.rb（追加分）

```ruby
  Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
                  'CLIENT-ID', # 実際はgoogleからとってきたIDが入ります
                  'SERCRET-ID', # 同様
                  skip_jwt: true ,
                  name: :google,
                  scope: %w(email) 
end
```

routes.rb

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  root to: "home#index"
  # devise_for :users
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
      omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
  }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`の置き場所は`app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`になってますか？違う場所に置いていたりファイル名やディレクトリ名が異なっていたりしませんか？

Answer (score 1):

すでにコメントにもありますが、Railsは定数（クラスを含みます）を自動読み込みする際にファイル名とディレクトリ構造が一致している必要があります（参考：https://railsguides.jp/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0）

> app/controllers/admin/payments_controller.rbではAdmin::PaymentsControllerを定義すべき

このように、`Users::OmniauthCallbacksController`は`app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`に置かれていないと正しく自動読み込みされません。